# How reliable is Cloud Firestore Billable Metrics?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I'm not setting up any listener for my queries. I've 3 documents and when I update a field in a document through the console, the very first time I see some 30 reads but every other time, if I change the same field (without modifying any code), I see 1 read.

I'm not sure what's going on. If perform a write after  an hour or so, I again see the very first operation results in 30 some reads.

Is Billable Metrics completely reliable? Or is there any better solution for this?

Comment: Whats does *when I update a field in a document through the console* mean specifically? What does the document and function call look like? (e.g. include the data you're working with). Activity in the console counts toward usage so *For example, if the console loads 500 documents then you'll be charged 500 reads.*

Comment: @Jay *Updating a field in a document through the console* means changing the value of a particular field in a particular document. There's no function except initializing the `FirebaseApp`.

Comment: Thanks. I got that. I was asking what specific steps are you using to update the document and then more about what your database looks like. I ask because both reads and writes in console count. So for example, I opened my console and clicked on a collection; because it was read in the console, the read count increased.

Comment: @Jay I change field and after a couple of mins I go to the usage tab, maybe 1-2 times this happens, but this still shouldn't increase my read count to 30 first time, and when I do the same thing subsequently it counts as just 1 read. So, I don't think this metrics is quite reliable. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you going back to the view that shows the collection(s)? If you click on one that has say... 30 documents, that could be 30 reads.

Comment: @Jay I do go back but I also go back after performing subsequent writes. So, I'm not doing anything special first time. Also, I only have 3 documents (total), so this 30 some numbers is out of place.

Comment: If this is a Firebase console issue, there really isn't anything we can do about here on SO. A great resource if [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) so I think a good first step is to reach out to them at  and file a report.

Comment: @Jay Thanks, I was going to do that but thought of keeping this question open for a couple of days. Appreciate your efforts :)